# error while reading information from an AJAX response with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this dataset returned to me by a method in C # aspx. However, whenever I want to iterate it, I get
undefined the data arrives, but I can't access the properties.

```
"[
  {
    "idFotografia": 96223,
    "Leyenda": "El Ministro de Salud, Oscar Ugarte, participó en el taller de comunicación de riesgo: \"La experiencia de la preparación contra la pandemia de influenza\". Foto: ANDINA / Rubén Grández.",
    "Descripcion": "",
    "Fecha": "2009-05-28T00:00:00",
    "Imagen": "000096223M.jpg",
    "Seccion": "Política",
    "Fotografo": "ANDINA/archivo",
    "URLPhoto": "http://andina.pe/agencia/foto-el-ministro-salud-oscar-ugarte-participo-el-taller-comunicacion-riesgo-experiencia-de-preparacion-contra-pandemia-influenza-foto-andina-ruben-grandez-96223.aspx"
  },
  {
    "idFotografia": 96226,
    "Leyenda": "El Ministro de Salud, Oscar Ugarte,declara luego de participar en el taller de comunicación de riesgo: \"La experiencia de la preparación contra la pandemia de influenza\". \r\nFoto: ANDINA / Rubén Grández.",
    "Descripcion": "",
    "Fecha": "2009-05-28T00:00:00",
    "Imagen": "000096226M.jpg",
    "Seccion": "Política",
    "Fotografo": "ANDINA/archivo",
    "URLPhoto": "http://andina.pe/agencia/foto-el-ministro-salud-oscar-ugartedeclara-luego-participar-el-taller-comunicacion-riesgo-experiencia-de-preparacion-contra-pandemia-influenza-\r\nfoto-andina-ruben-grandez-96226.aspx"
  }
]
```

"
And this is the method in Jquery that runs through it, however it always returns undefined

```
function _loadFotografiasLanding() {

var ruta = '/landing.aspx/loadFotografiasTags';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ruta,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row = "";
        $.each(response, function () {
            $.each(this, function (index, item) {
                row += "Leyenda: " + item.idFotografia;
            });
        });
        
        $("#fotografias").html(row);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error en la carga de Fotografias");
    },
});
```

Please help. =)

Comment: maybe try `JSON.parse()` the response first?

Comment: @Zaya That is done internally when `dataType:'json'` is set

Comment: hi guys, dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd loop iterates over the object and the `index` `value` is actually its string key & value.

You can access the specific key from the first loop itself by directly specifying it key. In your case `this['idFotografia']`

```js
var response = [
  {
    "idFotografia": 96223,
    "Leyenda": "El Ministro de Salud, Oscar Ugarte, participó en el taller de comunicación de riesgo: \"La experiencia de la preparación contra la pandemia de influenza\". Foto: ANDINA / Rubén Grández.",
    "Descripcion": "",
    "Fecha": "2009-05-28T00:00:00",
    "Imagen": "000096223M.jpg",
    "Seccion": "Política",
    "Fotografo": "ANDINA/archivo",
    "URLPhoto": "http://andina.pe/agencia/foto-el-ministro-salud-oscar-ugarte-participo-el-taller-comunicacion-riesgo-experiencia-de-preparacion-contra-pandemia-influenza-foto-andina-ruben-grandez-96223.aspx"
  },
  {
    "idFotografia": 96226,
    "Leyenda": "El Ministro de Salud, Oscar Ugarte,declara luego de participar en el taller de comunicación de riesgo: \"La experiencia de la preparación contra la pandemia de influenza\". \r\nFoto: ANDINA / Rubén Grández.",
    "Descripcion": "",
    "Fecha": "2009-05-28T00:00:00",
    "Imagen": "000096226M.jpg",
    "Seccion": "Política",
    "Fotografo": "ANDINA/archivo",
    "URLPhoto": "http://andina.pe/agencia/foto-el-ministro-salud-oscar-ugartedeclara-luego-participar-el-taller-comunicacion-riesgo-experiencia-de-preparacion-contra-pandemia-influenza-\r\nfoto-andina-ruben-grandez-96226.aspx"
  }
];

$.each(response, function () {
    console.log('Loop 1: ', this['idFotografia']);
    
    $.each(this, function (index, value) {
        console.log('Loop 2: ', index,' * ', value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if I put it, this['idFotografia'] it comes out undefined. what I want is to access the value of the properties. id, title, description etc.

Comment: Check the console message of the above snippet. Message Loop 1: access the value as this['idFotografia'] itself.

Comment: hi zam, thanks for response. 
if I run the code this comes out in the console Loop 1:  undefined

Comment: in the example you show it works, but not in my local development. I do not understand why

Comment: Have you verified you are getting response from the ajax call inside the success handler?

Comment: Lets continue discussion in this chat if you can join - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231796/ajax-success-undefined